# I have a table Products in my MySQL in xampp.It has ID,name,price,qty and img1,img2 column for image. I want to show the data in frontend

Tags: reactjs

So I have used multer to store the uploaded files in uploads folder in local storage using multer.My data entry is working fine.The two img columns contain unique filenames and actual files are in the uploads folder.In my frontend I want to show the Product details like this

```
`    <div className="row product-grid">
           {products.map((product) => (
            <div className="col-md-3 my-4" key={product.id}>
              <Link to={`/ProductWelcome/${product.id}`} className="product-link">
                <div className="product">
                  <div className="product-image">
                    {product.Images.map((image, index) => (
                      
                      <img
                        key={index}
                        src={`/uploads/${image}`}
                        alt={`${product.ProductName} Image ${index + 1}`}
                      />
                    ))}  
                      </div>
                      <div className="product-details">
                        <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:            highlightMatchingLetters(product.name, searchQuery) }} />
                        <p className="description">{product.description}</p>
                        <p className="price">{product.price}</p>
 `
```

Now here is an api I want to use to view images and relevant data in frontend

This is in my server,js file(in backend)

```
``app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '`your text`uploads')));

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  const sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching product data:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching product data' });
    } else {
      console.log('Fetched product data:', results);
      const productsWithImages = results.map((product) => ({
        ...product,
        Images: JSON.parse(product.Images),
      }));

      console.log('Fetched product data:', productsWithImages);
      
      // Assuming productsWithImages is an array of product objects with images.
      // You can also log the first product's image filenames for testing.
      if (productsWithImages.length > 0) {
        console.log('First product image filenames:', productsWithImages[0].Images);
      }

      res.json(productsWithImages);
    }
  });
});`
```

`
But its not working as expected.My products are not showing in frontend.Can someone help me ? I am doing this in react, using MYSQl database in xampp

I wanted the product image and data to be displayed in frontend but nothing is showing.Also the console log in my server,js is not printing anything.Is the data not being fetched properly? I have tried many things but can't figure it out.Please help me

Also this error is showing in frontend

Home.js:37 Error fetching product data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

**1**.If you are storing the actual binary image data in the img1 column (BLOB data type in MySQL), then product.img1 would be a binary buffer or data. In this case, you would need to handle the binary data appropriately to display it as an image. You might need to convert it to a data URL or use a library like react-image to display the image.

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.img1.toString('base64')}`} alt={product.name} />
```

**2**. Path to an Image: If you are storing the path to an image file in the img1 column, then product.img1 would be a string containing the file path. In this case, you would use this path in the src attribute of an  element in your HTML to display the image in your React frontend. The path would typically be a URL or a relative path to the image file on your server or a public URL.

```
<img src={product.img1} alt={product.name} />
```

Comment: Actually I am only storing the unique image file names in the database and not the entire filepath. Is it a better idea to store the path in the database. Also can you kindly take a look at the app.get api? I am using that api to get info from the database but I can't check whether the data is properly fetched or not as my console logs are not being triggered in backend.Could you guide me here a little?